# Как исправить ошибку VS2019 при опубликовании проекта Параметры - Entity Framework Migrations

Tags: c#, visual-studio, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, миграция

Открываю VS2019 v16.3.4 Опубликовать-Параметры-Entity-Framework-Migrations
Ошибка dbconext list --json
и дальше Сообщение об ошибке:

- dotnet ef dbcontext list --json
- 
- CategoryInfo : NotSpecified: (Не удалось выпо...указанный файл.:String) [], RemoteException
- FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError

Возможные причины:
* Вы неправильно набрали встроенную команду dotnet.
* Вы планировали выполнить программу .NET Core, однако dotnet-ef не существует.
* Вы хотели запустить глобальное средство, но по указанному в PATH пути не удалось найти исполняемый файл с префиксом dotnet, имеющий такое имя.

Comment: проверял на net core 3.0, 2.1 переустанавливал vs2019

Comment: поправьте кодировку вашего вывода, тут ж ничего не понятно

Comment: + dotnet ef dbcontext list --json
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo : NotSpecified: (Не удалось выпо...указанный файл.:String) [], RemoteException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError

Возможные причины:
* Вы неправильно набрали встроенную команду dotnet.
* Вы планировали выполнить программу .NET Core, однако dotnet-ef не существует.
* Вы хотели запустить глобальное средство, но по указанному в PATH пути не удалось найти исполняемый файл с префиксом dotnet, имеющий такое имя.

Comment: чем то похоже на это [“No executable found matching command dotnet-ef” error with EF Core database-first](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42898188/312041)

Comment: Спасибо!! Помогло! просто нужно выполнить dotnet tool install --global dotnet-ef

Comment: Я тут новичок. Как мне вас отметить?

Comment: На здоровье. Ничего делать не надо, просто отметье свой ответ как ответ когда у вас появится такая возможность.

Answer (score 4):

Спасибо tym32167.
Нужно глобально установить в консоли dotnet-ef

```
dotnet tool install --global dotnet-ef
```

Comment: А если нужно локально установить dotnet tool install --global dotnet-ef --global не подходит